# Get deterministic values from SecureRandom?

Tags: java, random

For benchmarking purposes, I'd like to have a SecureRandom produce deterministic output. Is this possible through the use of a seed (or maybe specification of an algorithm)?

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
class TestSecureRandom {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        rnd.setSeed(1);
        System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
    }
}
```

For me, the above program produces different values even though the seed is specified.

Comment: According to its javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) it is non-deterministic. `setSeed` only changes its internal state, but it remain non-deterministic.

Comment: Does it have to be a `SecureRandom`? Can it be some other kind of `Random` (for example, `Random` itself)?

Comment: No. Program to the `interface`. Use `Random` in code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is probably to make most of your code only depend on `Random`, with an instance being injected (e.g. by passing it into a constructor). That way, for testing purposes you can pass in a simple `Random` with a fixed seed - but for *real* runs where security is required, you can pass in an instance of `SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 9):

In order to override the default seed ,pass [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) algorithm name like this

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
class TestSecureRandom {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SecureRandom rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        rnd.setSeed("foo".getBytes("us-ascii"));
        System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
        System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Ouput

```
-207444710
-1693504542
```

Comment: I ended up using the `Random` interface, but this also useful to know.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is clearly explained in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random
>   number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic
>   algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed.
>   Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others
>   may use a combination of both techniques.

If you ask about implementation, in Linux it uses `/dev/urandom` so the result is  unpredictable. However, you can force `SecureRandom` to use another algorithm:

```
SecureRandom rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
```

But for many cases, most reasonable idea is to use some OOP patterns (e.g., [jon-skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341390/2865997)).