# Retrieve the seed of a SecureRandom number generator/Check if seed matches with random numbers generated from SecureRandom

Tags: java, cryptography

I have a requirement where I need to generate secure pseudorandom numbers using SecureRandom() in Java. For this, I have set a seed which was used for generating the other random numbers. Code is shown below

```
 SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

 //generate a given number of seed bytes (to seed other random number generators, for example):
 byte[] bytes = secureRandom.generateSeed(16);

 //print obtained bytes as string from array
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

 //to get random bytes, a caller simply passes an array of any length, which is then filled with random bytes:
 secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes);

 //print obtained bytes as string from array
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

The seeds that are used to generated these numbers will be stored in a local storage. My question is, if I have the random number, can I retrieve the seed from it? Or since I have the seeds locally stored, can I crosscheck the random numbers with the seeds and retrieve the matching seed?

Comment: If it is a secure RNG then by definition you cannot work backwards from the output to the seed material, no matter how much output you have.  Being able to discover the seed material from the output makes the RNG insecure.

Comment: Thanks! If i use the same seed (using setSeed()), would it generate the same sequence of random numbers? and by this, would I be able to match the random numbers I generated using the same seed, at a later point in time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get deterministic values from SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341294/get-deterministic-values-from-securerandom)

Comment: @PeterO. This is kind of my requirement. Please check my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499215/same-seed-different-random-numbers-java-securerandom-android
But I am facing some issues

Comment: In general a secure RNG is not solely dependent on the seed you give it.  There is other internal seed  material that you cannot access.  AIUI the Java secure RNG is like this.  Your supplied seed influences, but does not determine the output.  To do that you need a simpler, non-secure RNG.

Comment: @rossum Okay, I understand. What alternative is there that could help me achieve the same sequence based on a seed, but I need security as well.

Comment: Try an encryption.  Encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... with a given key and you will get a stream of (almost) random numbers.  As long as you use the same key you will get the same numbers.  My "almost" is because the numbers will not recur as with a true RNG.  Encrypting different inputs guarantees different outputs.  Use DES for 64 bit numbers, AES for 128 bit numbers.  In effect the key is your seed.